# Using for loop to iterate over a list of numbers with try and except

Tags: python

I want to write a program which repeatedly reads numbers until the user enters “done”.
Once “done” is entered, print out the total, count using for loop. this is the program I found after some searching :

```
c=0 #c=count t=total
t=0
while True:
    x=input('enter no.')
    try:
        x=float(x)
        c=c+1
        t=t+x
    except:
        if x=='done':
            break
   
print(c)
print(t)
```

The confusion regarding this program is why do we have to convert x to float type and where is the condition where we want to iterate over the list given by user, like for i in x and so on.

Comment: can you provide an example of the input/output you are expecting.

Comment: IIUC you don't need a for loop because you're using a `while` loop. This line: `t=t+x` keeps adding to your total, so you don't need to iterate over a list. Also, you turn `x` into a float because input is always initially  a string and you can't add strings as numbers

Comment: @JuanC thanks for the prompt and helpful reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From how you posted the question, you want to gather all the numbers a user enters, then print out the total count of all the numbers added together?

If that's what you mean, the previous solution you found is correct, but accomplishes this task differently: it adds the numbers *as* the user enters them, without storing them in a list. So it doesn't need a for loop in the end to add up all the numbers, it has already stored them all in a variable 't'. The program also doesn't need to count the number of numbers the user adds during the end because it has stored them in the variable 'c'

Meanwhile, you have to convert x to float as other answers have said because input() returns a string, not a number that can be added with. A float is a floating point number that Python *can* use to do math with.

Also and more importantly, the code uses x=float(x) as a test to see if x is a number. If x **isn't** a string that can be represented as a number (like 'done' but also 'abcd' or '1cd'), the code doesn't accept any input, but goes to the except block. Then, if the string also isn't 'done', it will go back to the top of the loop and ask the question again.

Example simple code that does use lists:

```
numberList = [] # stores our numbers
while True:
    uInput = input('Enter number:') # uInput is user input
    try:
        uInput=float(uInput)        # check if uInput is a float
        numberList.append(uInput)
    except:
        if uInput == 'done':
            break

totalVal = 0                        # get ready var to store total of numbers
count = 0
for n in numberList:
    totalVal = totalVal + n         # adds up values of each number
    count += 1

print(totalVal)                     # print total value of all numbers
print(count)                        # print number of values)
```

Alternatively, check out @Tom's answer: the Python [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sum) function adds up all values in a list. As well, the Python [len()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#len) function gives the number of elements in a list. So len(numberList) would have been the same as count in the above example code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't convert string into float,it raises a error

which is caught by except block where it checks is `x=="done"`

The correct way:

> To iterate over the numbers given by users

```
a=[]
while True:
    x=input("enter no:")
    if(x=="done"):
        break
    elif(x.isnumeric()):
        a.append(x)
    else:
        print("wrong")
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to float (it could also be `int`) because `input` returns a string. When that conversion fails, the code inside the `except` block is executed, so it checks if that input is `'done'` and if so it leaves the infinite loop.

```py
c = 0 #c=count t=total
t = 0
while True: # this is an infinite loop
    x = input('enter no.') # this is a string
    try:
        x = float(x) # string gets converted into a float
        c += 1 # this is the same as c = c + 1
        t += x # this is the same as t = t + x
    except:
        # an exception is raised if the string the user entered
        # could not be converted into a float

        # if input was not a number, then leave the loop if it is "done"
        if x == 'done':
            break
        # if input was not "done" continue allowing the user entering values
   
print(c)
print(t)
```

Comment: @SamyakJain, I would appreciate if you can validate my answer if this was useful for you.

Comment: dont you want to iterate over the list? @SamyakJain

Answer (score 0):

> why do we have to convert x to float type

`input` returns the user input as type `str`; adding `str` and numerical types (e.g. `float` or `int`) produces a `TypeError`. So, without converting the user input to a number,  the `try` block fails (since `t` is type `int`), and `t` is never updated.  The program doesn't break b/c the `try-except` is broad.  You can try this by removing `x=float(x)`; you will see that `print(t)` will always output `0`.

> where is the condition where we want to iterate over the list given by user

Your program is only storing the count of entries (in `c`) and the sum of entries (in `t`), but not the actual entries themselves.  So say, if the output is `2` for `c` and `4` for `t`, you know 2 numbers have been entered, but you cannot get back whether it was 0 & 4, 1 & 3, 2 & 2, etc....

You can instead add the entries to a list - this is saving more information (and using more memory), and you can then loop over all the user input if that's something you need to do:

```
c=0 #c=count t=total
t=[]
while True:
    x=input('enter no.')
    try:
        x=float(x)
        c=c+1
        t.append(x)
    except:
        if x=='done':
            break
   
print(c)      #shows how many numbers entered
print(t)      #shows that t is now a list of entries
print(sum(t)) #shows that you can still get the sum of entries
```